# Execute variation of query based on IF statement

Tags: oracle, if-statement, case

Try to explain this simply below.

A simple if statement (in reality will be like

```
if sysdate >= trunc(sysdate)+5/24
```

), set up parameters to be used in the query

```
if 2>=1 then
  define ThisTime = trunc(sysdate)-1
else
  define ThisTime = trunc(sysdate)

select *
from table
where time >= &ThisTime
```

The above doesn't work and I'm wondering if it is possible? Unfortunately its a static monitoring query that runs from sqltoolkit in itrs and I can't think of another way of choosing a rollover time.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do - if the current time is before 5am then get all data for yesterday; and if it's after 5am then get all data from today?

Comment: Essentially yeah but its a bit more complex.

Once the rollover time is hit a new 

- SLA Time
- OLA Time
- Expected Start time

Are also queried and this will be extended to ~ 30 different queries looking for results in the same table with different times for when you want to look at x date + all their target times

Comment: Can't you come up with a Normalised Table or a View that defines those 30 parameters which can easily be joined based on a common key - "SLA Time - OLA Time " with your final query ?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Yeah actually you're probably right, imagine I'll be waiting a long time for that to be done but it certainly seems the most efficient/plausible solution at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get data from yesterday if run before 5am, and data from today if run after 5am, then you can adjust the filter time by five hours before truncating it:

```
select *
from your_table
where time >= trunc(sysdate - 5/24)
and time < trunc(sysdate + 19/24)
```

When run at, say, 04:59, `sysdate - 5/24` evaluates to 23:59 yesterday, and `sysdate + 19/24` evaluates to 23:59 today; truncating those gives midnight yesterday and midnight today.

When run at, say, 05:01, `sysdate - 5/24` evaluates to 00:01 today, and `sysdate + 19/24` evaluates to 00:01 tomorrow; truncating those gives midnight today and midnight tomorrow.

Comment: Essentially  but its a bit more complex. Once the rollover time is hit a new - SLA Time - OLA Time - Expected Start time Are also queried and this will be extended to ~ 30 different queries looking for results in the same table with different times for when you want to look at x date + all their target times

So building it within the select statement wouldn't be ideal

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... are you running 30 queries in a script and want to define a substitution variable once (as your `define` and `&` in the question kind of suggest)? How does that fit in with ITRS SQL Toolkit? The docs for that suggest it runs a query, rather than calling out to SQL\*Plus say, though it isn't somethign I've used. You seem to want to run many queries, so what happens to those results?

Comment: So they are monitoring alerts in ITRS, it will be 30 different alerts set up pointing to the respective rows in the main table.

Perhaps you're right that `define` and `&` won't work as they are SQL*Plus? (Apologies but I've barely touched db's before today)

The suggestion above by Kaushik is probably what I will have to go with but unfortunately will take some time to get implemented due to procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the decision as an OR, even if it will perform quite poorly in most cases (I tend to avoid OR conditions):

```
select *
  from table
 where (sysdate >= trunc(sysdate)+5/24 and time >= trunc(sysdate))
       or (sysdate < trunc(sysdate)+5/24 and time >= trunc(sysdate) - 1)
```

Comment: My issue is the query is actually quite a bit longer, referencing more defined times and wanting it to be used for ~30 different queries by simply changing the defined parameters.

I probably should've mentioned that, apologies